# Add plus sign "+" before input value in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, phone-number, input-field

The question sounds pretty easy, but I could found any clear solution for it.

I have custom input field (I'm using reactive forms approach) for phone numbers. The aim is to always have a plus sign before input value.

Requirements:

- the entire input value including plus sign should be selectable (i.e. the hack with adding span-s or div-s with plus sign before input is not acceptable)
- if the input value is empty - the plus sign can be removed, otherwise it should be added at the beginning of the input value if we add numbers
- using third party libraries is not acceptable
- when patching the form control with the new value (for example '123456') - it should also add plus sign before

How can we implement this logic in Angular2 project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that you could bind to the `(change)` event of your `input`:

```
processInput(inputVal: string = null) {
    if (!inputVal) {
        inputVal = this.myForm.get('myInput').value; // since you're using reactive forms
    }

    if (inputVal === '') {
        // Do nothing
    } else if (inputVal.match(/^\d*$/)) {
        if (!inputVal.includes('+')) {
            inputVal = '+' + inputVal;
        }
    }

    // Then patch your 'myInput' value in your form with 'inputVal'
    this.myForm.patchValue({ 'myInput': inputVal });
}

safePatchMyInput(value: string) {
    this.processInput(value);
}
```

This implementation will add a plus sign if (and only if) the input string contains purely numbers. It also allows you to empty the input entirely (including the plus sign).

**Edit:** *The addition of the `safePatchMyInput` method will allow you to manually patch that input and still utilize the same input processing from the previous funciton. (This means adding the default parameter to the previous funciton)*

Binding to the `(change)` event on your input would simply look like this:

```
<input (change)="processInput()"/>
```

## Edit 2

Here is an updated solution that works with `FormControl.registerOnChange` to process the input even if it was set manually via `patchValue`.

Angular Component:

```
myForm: FormGroup;

constructor() {
  this.myForm = new FormGroup({
    'myInput': new FormControl('')
  })
}

ngOnInit() {
  const myInput = this.myForm.get('myInput') as FormControl;
  myInput.registerOnChange(this.processInput);
}

processInput = () => {
  let inputVal = this.myForm.get('myInput').value;

  if (inputVal === '') {
    // Do nothing
  } else if (inputVal.match(/^\d*$/)) {
    if (!inputVal.includes('+')) {
      inputVal = '+' + inputVal;

      // Then patch your 'myInput' value in your form with 'inputVal'
      this.myForm.patchValue({ 'myInput': inputVal });
    }
  }
}
```

HTML Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input formControlName="myInput" (input)="processInput()"/>
</form>
```

[Stackblitz, for reference.](https://angular6-sherlock-s6tsgf.stackblitz.io)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but there are two issues: the plus sign doesn't appear on first keypress (probably there should be `(input)="..."` event binding). And also when I'm patching the form control with new value - there is no plus sign before it. Also added your example in this [stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-sherlock-dzrm5x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), check it out.

Comment: Your suggestion of using the `(input)` binding is valid. That will cause the value to update on each keypress.

Comment: But there is still an issue with the last requirement: 'when patching the form control with the new value (for example '123456') - it should also add plus sign before'

Comment: You can add a `safePatch` function to handle that (which in-turn calls the `processInput` function. Check out [this fork of your stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-sherlock-s6tsgf).

Comment: Thnx for your effort. Pretty good solution, but as I mentioned in my question - I have custom phone input field. In real project there is a lot of large form groups with multiple phone inputs. And when I fetch data - I only call `patchValue` method for the entire formGroup. So we need somehow encapsulate this savePatch logic inside the custom input component itself.

Answer (score 1):

I put something together quickly, the code needs refactoring but in essence it does what you have asked for. You can subscribe to the valueChanges event on the formControl, here you can do all the modification to the value that you need to produce the desired result. Link to Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9mubgr

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular';
  myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      'myInput': new FormControl('')
    })
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm.get('myInput').valueChanges.subscribe((inputValue) => {
      if(inputValue === this.myForm.get('myInput')) {
        return;
      }

      if(inputValue.length === 0) {
        return;
      }

      if(inputValue.legth !== 0 && inputValue.slice(0,1) !== '+') {
        this.myForm.get('myInput').setValue('+' + this.myForm.get('myInput').value);
      }
    });
  }

  patch() {
    this.myForm.patchValue({ 'myInput': '123' })
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice, but if I'm patching form without emiting an event ( `this.myForm.patchValue({ 'myInput': '123' }, { emitEvent: true })` ), this will not work as expected.